Resolved run Karate Test/Debug options not displayed in Visual Studio Code
I have also encountered the same issue that my run Karate Test/Debug options is not displayed in Visual Studio Code.
What I did and tried:

From extension tab, uninstall the Karate and Karate Runner extensions.
After that, close Visual Studio Code.
Open Visual Studio Code, reinstall only the Karate Runner extension and done.

After using the method above, I am able to see my run Karate Test/Debug options in Visual Studio Code.
Note: Hope the above method help. Thanks.

I think the best place to get support for the "karate runner" is the github issues tracker for that 3rd party project
